# Making an actionListener for a single JButton that has parameters able to work properly

Tags: java

I don't think this a very complicated question but I have no idea to solve it. If you take a look at the code I have below, it uses one JButton with X, Y parameters to create a grid of buttons, like so:

[image]

Now if you look toward the bottom of the code at the actionListener, there is an if statement that prints out "2-2 has been pressed!" if button 2-2 has been pressed. For this program I plan to make the grid able to be sized based on user input though (e.g. the user inputs 3,5 and it creates a 3 by 5 grid of buttons), so writing an if statement for every button seems like something a moron would do...

So my question is this: is it possible to make the actionListener able to do something like print out the coordinates of a button pressed without doing something ridiculous like creating an if statement for every button?

I have tried to do things like referencing x and y from inside the actionListener but it doesn't work because they are in the for Loop of the public Testing constructor

```
import java.awt.GridLayout; //imports GridLayout library
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Testing extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //creates frame
    JButton[][] grid; //names the grid of buttons



    public Testing(int width, int length) { //constructor
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length)); //set layout
        grid = new JButton[width][length]; //allocate the size of grid

        for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                grid[x][y] = new JButton("(" + x + "," + y + ")"); //creates new button     
                frame.add(grid[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                grid[x][y].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testing(5, 5); /*length and width of the grid in terms of number        of buttons */
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == grid[2][2]) {
            System.out.println("2-2 Has been pressed");
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: I would extend JButton to create my own version, which will have a variable `name` in it. Then whenever pressed I would get the name (e.g. 2-2) and print it out...

Comment: `grid[x][y].setActionCommand(x + ":" + y);` `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
System.out.println(Button " + button.getActionCommand() + " was pressed.");
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so writing an if statement for every button seems like something a moron would do...

Correct, but creating a grid to get user input also doesn't make sense.

Maybe use maybe two combo boxes, or two JSpinners to represent the x/y values.

Then you click on a "Make Grid" button and get the value from the two components.

Another option is to use the "action command" of the button:

```
JButton button = new JButton("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
button.setActionCommand(x + ":" + y);
button.addActionListener(this);
grid[x][y] = button;button     
frame.add(button); //adds button to grid
```

Then in the ActionListener you can access the action command:

```
String command = event.getActionCommand();
String[] values = command.split(":");
int x = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
int y = ...
```

Or you used a double loop to create the buttons, so why can't you use a double loop to search for the button?

Comment: That second solution works great, thank you very much for helping me!